# Typo3 slow List-view module

Tags: listview, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

The list-view module in one of my Typo3 installations is painfully slow.
Clicking on a folder or one of the contents takes forever to be displayed.
Everything else is working fine and fast.

Any ideas what the cause for this could be?

Typo3 6.2.25

Comment: How many records do you have on this page? Is it slow on every page?

Comment: Only about three. It's avery short list.